# ruby on rails store sql result on a variable

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, variables

Newbie here. I am trying to store the result of my search onto a variable.

```
@answer = q.answers.select(:name) which runs 
"SELECT name FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = 1;" and returns 
"t" for true.
```

It runs fine on the command line and shows the right result. But I want to compare that result to another variable.

How do i extract that result? @answer[0], or @answer, or answer_var = @answer[0]
i.e.

```
if @answer == some_other_variable  OR
     if @answer[0] == some_other_variable  OR
     if answer_var == some_other_variable
```

what value do @answer[0] and @answer[0] hold and how can I print the value to the log file? not the web page. I know it must be simple, but I can't get my head around it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really an answer to your question but...

If you want to follow "the rails way", you should better use Models and not deal with SQL at all.

E.g. :

```
@answer = q.answers.first # answers is an array, take the first
if @answer.name == ...
```

For the logging, I suggest you that : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html#the-logger